# Propiedad siempre NULL en Rest Api

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-4

Tengo la siguiente entidad:

```
public class EntityBase<T> where T : class
{
    [DataMember]
    public int CurrentItemCount { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int ItemsPerPage { get; set; }


    [DataMember]
    public int StartIndex { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int PageIndex { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<T> Items { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public T Item { get; set; }

    public EntityBase() { }}
```

Tengo este servicio REST:

```
public EntityBase<Person> GetPerson(PersonFilter personFilter)
```

Que llamo desde un HttpClient:

```
public T GetPostSync<T, TR>(string requestUri, string entityId = null, TR filter = null) where TR : class where T : class
    {
        var uri = string.Format(requestUri, entityId);
        var responseMessage = _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(uri, filter).Result;
        responseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        if (responseMessage.Content == null)
            return default(T);

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
    }
```

Al deserializar, las propiedades Items e Item, siempre me devuelve null.

¿Por qué?

Un saludo,

Comment: Hola, puedes mostrar un `Json` de respuesta? Para poder analizar si la estructura de tu modelo es correcta o no según el `Json` recibido.

Comment: Hola, de todas formas vao que estás realizando un `POST`, es correcto? No estás intentando realizar un `GET`? No veo que estés enviando ningún cuerpo de mensaje en tu llamada al servicio.

Comment: Ya está solucionado. Gracias!

Comment: Hola @Nacho, puedes mostrar la solución? Muchas gracias

Comment: Al final tengo esto:
StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(param), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, stringContent);